# In a graph, is O(n*m) complexity considered polynomial or what?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to understand if *O(n*m)* is considered polynomial, given *m* and *n* are the sizes of two **independent** inputs?

I just want to clarify the concept of polynomial time in here and want to know if *O(n*m)* has a different name for its type of complexity. How de we represent it in a graph ?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that m>n. Then `O(n*m) < O(m^2)`, the latter being obviously polynomial. So O(n*m) is also in polynomial.

Comment: is it the same for O(n*m*k .. ) or only apply to O(n*m) ?

Comment: @SalimDz, yes, you can have any finite number of parameters. Take maximum m, and your time will be bounded by `O(m^N)`, which is polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is polynomial. Basically, until you don't see `n` and `m` as exponents in `Big O` it is polynomial.

You can see it like this:

- *Polynomial*. When the complexity of the algorithm is described by some polynomial function. (e.g `O(n*m)`, `O(n^3 * log m)` etc)
- *Exponential*. When the complexity of the algorithm is described by some exponential function. (e.g `O(m * 2^(n))`, `O(3^n * log m)` etc)

Comment: Strictly speaking, `log m` is not polynomial. But since `O(log m) < O(m)` we see that `O(log m)` is within polynomial boundaries.

Comment: Where did i say that?